# UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment

Tags: python, matplotlib

Most probably matplotlib 1.5.1 have installed in your machine and you may experience to get this kind of warning:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273: UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.
  warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to take a [tour] and read the [help]. We encourage users to answer their own questions when they find the solution. At the same time, the question needs to be an actual question. See [ask] for some tips on asking a good question.

Answer (score -5):

**To rid off from this warning please upgrade matplotlib by:**

```
*sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib*
```

Comment: While upgrading matplotlib is in general a good idea, this has nothing to do with the font-cache.

Comment: –1 don't recommend people to use sudo with pip, this can really muck things up

Comment: Actually I rid of the problem using this command and I shared my solution. If you have another solution please let us know